# Making only one navigation bar in Navigation Stack transparent iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uinavigationcontroller, uistoryboardsegue

I have a navigationcontroller with navigation flows as shown below:

NC -> A -> B

B appears through a push segue.

The navigationbar of A is made transparent using following

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    self.navigationController!.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
    self.navigationController!.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
    self.navigationController!.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
}
```

and is translucency is set to false in viewWillDisappear so that B can have the usual navigation bar:

```
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidDisappear(animated)
    self.navigationController!.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
}
```

The issue is that when Back button is pressed in B to return to A, The navigation bar of B appears momentarily before disappearing. How to solve this issue?

PS: I do not want to add code to overridden methods of B as B might be shared by other navigation controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The issue is that when Back button is pressed in B to return to A, The
>   navigation bar of B appears momentarily before disappearing. How to
>   solve this issue?

You do not need to toggle anything in your `viewWillDisappear` method. Just toggle everything in your `viewWillAppear` method in your every screens.

Is this what you want? If so, I made a sample project on Github just for you, and for other people who are new to iOS in the future.

https://github.com/glennposadas/showhidenavbar-ios

Though it uses my very simple cocoapod, you can just copy everything from my framework and sample project.

[image]

Comment: Many Thanks for taking time to answer and create a nice project Glenn. So it turned out, based on your answer that the key was to use         self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: true/false) appropriately in viewWillAppear(). Very clean and simple.